# using statement in codebehind

Tags: wpf, namespaces

When editing the c# programs I have the top that includes namespaces with the `using` keyword. Such as `using System;`.

I have some classes that are redundantly implemented across my WPF application. I would like to create a single reference point to use the methods within the whole application.

for instance when I perform data binding for ComboBoxes I have a class that includes this...

```
public class ComboBoxItemSource : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Source { get; set; }
    public Item Selected { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to have this in one place and include it in a reference rather than create it in each ViewModel that will need a combobox binding.

Comment: You must be having a root base class for VMs. If you haven't , make one , and place all such stuff there. As it will be placed in a super base class like Object class in C#, you can access it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to just put the class in a separate file and add it to your project.

Or even simpler:

- Right click on your project in the Solution Explorer -> "Add new Item" -> "Class".
- Copy/Paste your class into the file
- Adjust the namespace
- Add the missing usings to the file (especially the using for the "View Model Base")

The class including the namespace in the file will now look similar to this:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class ComboBoxItemSource : ViewModelBase
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Item> Source { get; set; }
        public Item Selected { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

Create an IComboBox interface:

```
public interface IComboBox
{
   ObservableCollection<Item> Source { get; set; }
   Item Selected { get; set; }
}
```

then you could create a Class that inherits from your ViewModelBase and implements your IComboBox:

```
public class ComboBoxVM :ViewModelBase, IComboBox
{
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Source
    {
        get
        {
            // do stuff
            return _source;
        }
        set { _source = value; }
    }

    public Item Selected
    {
        get
        {
            // do stuff
            return _selected;
        }
        set { _selected = value; }
    }
}
```

then in your ComboBoxItemSource, inherit from ComboBoxVM:

```
public class ComboBoxItemSource : ComboBoxVM
{

}
```

Hopefully this helps.